# Monitoring software for embedded application

Tags: embedded, ethernet, datalogger, host

I'm looking for a Windows application to collect data to a host PC from an embedded application (PIC microcontroller).
The communication between host and embedded application is via Ethernet.

It would have to be the application that sends data rather than the host go read them.

I was away on a solution using SNMP (with MRTG on the host PC, for example) but this protocol does not send data when they are present on the embedded application : the host retrieves the data at regular intervals.
If the host was a UNIX machine, I could use inetd to start the recovery values ​​with MRTG but I don't know an Windows equivalent (and I do not have the skills to program a Windows service).

My next solution is to use a HTTP server on host and send data via GET or POST.

But perhaps there is a better solution. Do you know of software that would do that?

Thanks

Comment: If your problem is the PC-side, StackOverflow would be better; if you're looking for a protocol for the uC to communicate with the PC, then it's different. What's the connection now? USB?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution, for the moment. The embedded application is under development (but not by me) so it doesn't have connection yet but it would be Ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what type of data you're logging at what intervals, etc.

But, you might consider syslog over UDP http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-syslog-transport-udp-00.txt

UDP is relatively simple to implement over your ethernet controller.

syslog is standard in unix and [supported in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430107/open-source-syslog-daemon-for-windows).

Comment: This is an elegant solution that I like. Especially since syslog is ported to Windows. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org)?

Comment: It looks to me already better than my webserver solution. But that of syslog over UDP is even better.